# Automatic metrical appendix for plays (and long poems)

Tags: macros, cross-referencing, packages

Some editions of ancient plays (e.g. Loeb Classical Library and Oxford Classical Texts) have a separate metrical appendix that lists the meter used in each line of the play.

It looks something like this (quote from Terence. The Woman of Andros. The Self-Tormentor. The Eunuch. Edited and translated by John Barsby. Loeb Classical Library 22. Cambridge, MA: Harvard University Press, 2001.):

```
METRICAL ANALYSIS
 
Andria
 
1-174 iamb. sen.  
175-179 mutatis modis canticum  
  175 iamb. oct.  
  176 iamb. dim.
  177 iamb. oct.
  178-179 troch. sept.
etc.
```

Basically a list of things that I have marked earlier next to each line of the play itself. How could this be created in LaTeX?

There must be a package but I just can't find the correct keywords for search or see the obvious use of another package. None of the poetry packages have it. Even `reledmac` seems to miss this feature.

Comment: I have no idea how you have marked things earlier. Perhaps the `pagenote` package, which lets you put flagged items later in the document as endnotes, might help.

Comment: @PeterWilson Thank you for the idea. Maybe extending that package could solve this. I'm unsure how easy it would be to count same entries and print line ranges, but this is a start. 

Regarding marking lines: I'm willing to do it any way possible, probably a custom command like `\meter{iamb. sen.}` after the line. But the line number should be passed automatically there.